# what is sforce. class in Salesforce?

Tags: api, salesforce, apex-code, force.com

Just random pick some methods that I have found:

```
 sforce.connection.describeSObject
 sforce.SearchResult
 sforce.sObject
 sforce.LeadConvert()
 sforce.connection.create()
```

I just want to know what is this class for? and where can I find documentation for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want to know what is this class for?

These objects/methods are for accessing the Salesforce API using AJAX.  Before Visualforce became available, this was the library you'd use from within s-Controls to access the API.  You'd include connection.js like this:

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/24.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> and where can I find documentation for it?

[Salesforce AJAX Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index.htm).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link to the salesforce.com apex language reference guide, you should find the answers in here.

http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=apex%20language%20guide&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.salesforce.com%2Fus%2Fdeveloper%2Fdocs%2Fapexcode%2Fsalesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf&ei=KxN5T7ztC4KciQfLvbjTBA&usg=AFQjCNGme-573unHtICuF_tL5zG_vXkVsg&cad=rja